# SWIG-generated Lua<-->C++ Wrapper mishandling primitive types renamed by typedef

Tags: c++, lua, typedef, swig

I use SWIG to generate a C++ <--> Lua wrapper for a work project.
my main problem is, in this project at the base there exist type definitions for each platform. E.g. for Win32 there exists a header Win32Types.h where things like

```
typedef char Char;
typedef char TChar;
typedef signed int Int;
typedef unsigned int UInt;
typedef signed char Int8;
typedef unsigned char UInt8;
...
```

are defined.
The problem is now, with an example class like

```
class Named
{
  public:
    Named();
    virtual ~Named();

    void setName(const Char *name);
    const Char* GetName() const;
}
```

, the `setName`- Method generated in the SWIG-wrapper looks something like this:

```
static int _wrap_Named_SetName(lua_State* L) {
  int SWIG_arg = 0;
  Named *arg1 = (Named *) 0 ;
  Char *arg2 = (Char *) 0 ;

  SWIG_check_num_args("Named::SetName",2,2)

  if(!SWIG_isptrtype(L,1))
    SWIG_fail_arg("Named::SetName",1,"Named *");

  if(!SWIG_isptrtype(L,2)) 
    SWIG_fail_arg("Named::SetName",2,"Char const *");

  if (!SWIG_IsOK(SWIG_ConvertPtr(L,1,(void**)&arg1,SWIGTYPE_p_Named,0))){
    SWIG_fail_ptr("Named_SetName",1,SWIGTYPE_p_Named);
  }

  if (!SWIG_IsOK(SWIG_ConvertPtr(L,2,(void**)&arg2,SWIGTYPE_p_Char,0))){
    SWIG_fail_ptr("Named_SetName",2,SWIGTYPE_p_Char);
  }

  ...
}
```

the problem here is, the wrapper tries to treat Char as just another class pointer, although it is just a char pointer renamed to Char. 
is there any way to circumvent this behaviour?

i tried to write a typemap like

```
%typemap(in) Char {
  $1 = lua_tostring($input);
}
```

, but im not sure i did it the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two easier ways you can do this:

1. Show SWIG the `typedef`s for that platform, probably using `%include`
2. Tell SWIG to just use the normal `unsigned char *` typemap using `%apply`:

   ```
   %apply unsigned char * { const Char * }
   ```